# how to append a division to a division using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a division to a division using `.append()` of  jquery. But my code is not appending the division.

My code is:

```
    for(var k = 0,len=data.shareInfo.length;k<len;k += 1){
    var newcommhtml = '<div id="S0'+thecid+'" class="snew">';
    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<div class="author-image"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+data.shareInfo[k].senderPicture+'" alt="'+data.shareInfo[k].uname+'" width="100%" height="100%" class="ava"></div><span>'+data.shareInfo[k].uname+' shared the image '+data.shareInfo[k].imname+'</span>';
    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<div class="s-content"><div class="s-message"><span>'+nl2br(data.shareInfo[k].message+'</span></div><div class="shpicture">');
    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+data.shareInfo[k].image+'" alt="'+data.shareInfo[k].imname+'" width="100%" height="100%" data-id="'+data.shareInfo[k].id+'" data-alid="'+data.shareInfo[k].alid+'" data-shareid="'+data.shareInfo[k].shareId+'">';
    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '</div></div>';
    var thelm = "#S0"+thecid;
    $('#spscrl').append(newcommhtml);
    $(thelm).hide().fadeIn('slow');
    var newcommhtml=null;
    newcommhtml ='<div class="SPcommentbox">';
    newcommhtml = newcommhtml + '<div class="comment"><div class="commenter-image">';
    newcommhtml = newcommhtml +'</div><div class="commentername">';
    newcommhtml = newcommhtml +'</div><div class="addcomment"><input type ="text" placeholder="Write a comment..." class="commentbox"></input></div></div>';
    var selector='#S'+thecid;
    $(selector).append(newcommhtml);
    thecid++;
    }
```

The code will able to append the `divs` to `#spscrl`. But it is not able to append to `selector` `(#S+thecid)`, If I try to add using `class` that is, `.snew` it append the `division`. **Note that** I'm adding the divs with jQuery...

Please anyone help me to solve this problem... Thanks...

Comment: You forgot a zero. Shouldn't it be: `var selector='#S0'+thecid;`?

Comment: Thanks.... I really forgot that... Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the ID of `newcommhtml` to `S0`+`theCid`, so first an 's', *then a zero* and then the contents of `theCid`. Later, you try to recreate that ID **but forget the zero**! That would explain why this approach works the first, but not the second time.

So change:

```
var selector='#S'+thecid;
```

Into:

```
var selector='#S0'+thecid; // THE ZERO!
```

But I can't say for sure without seeing the content of `theCid`.

Comment: Haha, I always forget! @james

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me, a parent div can never be over a child div. @james

Comment: Sorry I missed the child `div` overriding the parent `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You `selector` variable is wrong.

Also you increase the readability of the code using some more tweaks like using [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for iteration, using `+=` operator for concatination and using method chaining like `ar thelm = $(newcommhtml).hide().appendTo('#spscrl').fadeIn('slow');`

```
$.each(data.shareInfo, function(i, v) {
    var newcommhtml = '<div id="S0' + thecid + '" class="snew">';
    newcommhtml += '<div class="author-image"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'
            + v.senderPicture
            + '" alt="'
            + v.uname
            + '" width="100%" height="100%" class="ava"></div><span>'
            + v.uname
            + ' shared the image ' + v.imname + '</span>';
    newcommhtml += '<div class="s-content"><div class="s-message"><span>'
            + nl2br(v.message + '</span></div><div class="shpicture">');
    newcommhtml += '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + v.image + '" alt="'
            + v.imname + '" width="100%" height="100%" data-id="' + v.id
            + '" data-alid="' + v.alid + '" data-shareid="' + v.shareId + '">';
    newcommhtml += '</div></div>';

    $('#spscrl').append(newcommhtml);

    var thelm = $(newcommhtml).hide().appendTo('#spscrl').fadeIn('slow');

    newcommhtml = '<div class="SPcommentbox">';
    newcommhtml += '<div class="comment"><div class="commenter-image">';
    newcommhtml += '</div><div class="commentername">';
    newcommhtml += '</div><div class="addcomment"><input type ="text" placeholder="Write a comment..." class="commentbox"></input></div></div>';
    $(newcommhtml).appendTo(thelm);
    thecid++;
});
```

There is not need to use `var newcommhtml` twice or to use `newcommhtml=null`;